# animated HTML/CSS/jQuery Skills Graph

Tags: jquery, html, css, graph

So I am trying to make a 'skills' graphic that loads up when the page is opened.

Using html, css, and jquery; but I cannot figure out why the little progress bars won't display the load action.I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction (hint) or find out whats wrong!

Here it is:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXJkt/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Skills</title>
<style>

#resumeProficiencies {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px 0px 30px 30px;
}

#resumeProficienciesTop {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#resumeProficienciesBottom {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.progress {
    background:#e9e5e2;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dddddd), to(#e9e5e2));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #e9e5e2);  
    height:20px; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;   
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bbbbbb inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;     
}

.adobe, .html, .css, .jquery, .javascript, .bootstrap, .wordpress, .ui, .ux, .rwd, .mobile, .rapidproto {

 -webkit-transition: width 4.50s ease !important;
 -moz-transition: width 4.50s ease !important;
   -o-transition: width 4.50s ease !important;
      transition: width 4.50s ease !important;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="resumeProficiencies">

       <div id="resumeProficienciesTop" class="resumeProficienciesTop1">adobe creative suite cc</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

       <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="adobe progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

      <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">html5</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

     <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="html progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->   

     <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">css3/css</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

     <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="css progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->   

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">jquery</div><!-- END resumeProficienciesTop -->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="jquery progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"></div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">javascript</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="javascript progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">bootstrap</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="bootstrap progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">wordpress</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="wordpress progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->   

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">user interface (ui)</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="ui progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- ENDresumeProficienciesBottom-->   

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">user experience (ux)</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="ux progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->   

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">responsive web design</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="rwd progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
         <span class="sr-only"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">mobile app design</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="mobile progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
         <span class="sr-only"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesTop">rapid prototyping</div><!--END resumeProficienciesTop-->

    <div id="resumeProficienciesBottom">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="rapidproto progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
         <span class="sr-only"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--END resumeProficienciesBottom-->   
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.adobe').css('width', '20%');
  $('.html').css('width', '100%');
  $('.css').css('width', '100%');
  $('.lesssass').css('width', '50%');
  $('.jquery').css('width', '70%');
  $('.javascript').css('width', '55%');
  $('.bootstrap').css('width', '90%');
  $('.wordpress').css('width', '85%');
  $('.ui').css('width', '100%');
  $('.ux').css('width', '90%');
  $('.rwd').css('width', '85%');
  $('.mobile').css('width', '85%');
  $('.rapidproto').css('width', '95%');
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lots of code = JSFiddle please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you forgot to set background and height to the ".progress-bar".

so, your css code should embed:

```
.progress-bar {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

[here is your exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/LXJkt/2/)

Comment: Is there a way I can activate the animation when some scrolls to the parent div?